# WireGuard via systemd-networkd but with /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf

Tags: arch-linux, wireguard, systemd-networkd

Is there any solution to use `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` for both, `wg-quick` and `systemd-networkd`.

Following [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WireGuard#systemd-networkd) example I have to duplicate configuration, but I want to store config in one place.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a soft link.
ln -s /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf /etc/systemd/network/99-wg0.netdev

Then you can edit from /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf and it changes at /etc/systemd/network/99-wg0.netdev, as it is the same file.